# Add a cookie during the Spring Security login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies, spring-security

I have a web project with Spring Security and I have tried to save a cookie in the method that process the authentication success. However, when I look to the browser's cookies only appears the JSESSIONID one, and the same happens when I look to request.getCookies() at the servlet that Spring redirects to.

I have tried to save the cookie in one of the application's servlets and the cookie is saved correctly, so maybe Spring Security cleans the response. Do you have any idea?

One workaround would be to save it in Session, and then get it and save the cookie on the servlet to which the login redirects. Another one would be saving the cookie with javascript like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351554/set-and-read-cookies-in-spring-mvc-security). But I don't like these solutions. Thanks in advance

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    ...
    // save a cookie with the selected language
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    if (parameterMap.containsKey("language")) {
        saveCookie("language", parameterMap.get("language")[0], response);
    }
}

public static void saveCookie(String cookieName, String value, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, value);
    //maxAge is one month: 30*24*60*60 
    cookie.setMaxAge(2592000);
    cookie.setDomain("projectName");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}

<security:http auto-config="false" ...>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.do" authentication-success-handler-ref="redirectRoleStrategy" .../>
    ...
</security:http>

<bean id="redirectRoleStrategy" class="com.companyName.security.RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="roleUrlMap">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="ROLE_ADMIN" value="/privat/application.do"/>
            ...
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you setting the cookie before or after calling super in the RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler?

```
 super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
```

You must set the cookie **before** your call to the super, as the logic in the superclass will send a redirect and therefore prevent you from updating content of the HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vschafer, your solution solved the problem! I didn't think about it because my code was executed after the redirect.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: @VladimírSchäfer is that possible spring security redirected `url` `set-cookie` possible in java side

Answer (score 0):

Try to call some harcoded value outside the if clause, just to see if it works:

```
saveCookie("language", "en", response);
```

Also as a test try to not set cookie domain and path initially:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, value);
//maxAge is one month: 30*24*60*60 
cookie.setMaxAge(2592000);
//cookie.setDomain("projectName");
//cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

It should be possible to set a cookie from the authentication successful handler, this should normally work.